# Create a new Stripe user on a paid plan, setting a trial period, without a Credit Card

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Using the Stripe API, Creating a new user on a paid plan with a trial period doesn't seem to work without a credit card token.

I am using the PHP SDK and doing the following:

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    "source" => NULL,
    "plan" => 'PROFESSIONAL',
    "email" => $email_address,
    "trial_end" => $unix_timestamp
);
```

Which returns the error:

> Error: Invalid source object: must be a dictionary or a non-empty string.

There are two reasons I think this should work, which is why I think I am doing something wrong.

1. Adding `trial_end` adds a trial to the subscription, so no payment is needed which means it doesn't need a Credit Card at that point in time.
2. Using the Stripe online Portal, you can create a user on a paid subscription, and also move existing users on to a paid subscription without the need for a Credit Card, when you specify a trial period. If you can do it in the portal, why can't you do it via the API?

Is there something I have missed in the Documentation to allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried the following which worked.

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    "plan" => 'PROFESSIONAL',
    "email" => $email_address,
    "trial_end" => $unix_timestamp
);
```

Basically I just removed the `source` key/value completely. It then created the user on the paid plan with the trial.

Odd behaviour as when you create a user on a FREE plan, you can have the `source` key there with a value of `NULL` and it works. Also not documented as far as I can see.

Comment: You should never pass a null parameter to `source`. Simply don't pass the parameter instead.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these step

1. Create a customer using

   \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
                       "description" => $descriptions,
                       "email" =>  $email
                   ));
2. Store the returned customer ID from stripe
3. Now subscribe the customer for that plan

   $customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($customer_id);

   $subscriptions = $customer->subscriptions->create(array("plan" => $plan_id));

Please make sure plan is already created on stripe.