# Error creating paid plan with trial Laravel Cashier

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

Simple problem but I cannot for the life of me figure this out.

I have 3 subscriptions on my Stripe account, one that's free and two that are paid with a 14 day trial period (set-up in Stripe). Everything works fine, except that when I go to subscribe new users to the paid trial plans right away I keep getting an error about the customer not having a payment source on file. My code looks like this:

```
// Create new User
$user = new Account($validatedUserData);

// Create Stripe user and subscribe to plan. Laravel automatically adds Stripe Customer ID 
// Free plan, create customer and subscribe to free plan in one line of code 
if ($planInRequest == 1) { 
    $user->newSubscription('My Subscription', 'Free Plan')->create(null, ['email' => $user->email]); 
} 

// If Paid plan...
else { 
     // Create user in Stripe first (this works) 
     $user->createAsStripeCustomer(null);

     // Subscribe user to paid plan with trial period
     $user->newSubscription('My Subscription', $planToUse)->create(null, ['email' => $user->email]); }
```

However, when I run this code I get the error

> No Payment Source exists for Customer.

I know I haven't added a Stripe Source to the customer yet (hence passing null), but I thought if there was a free trial period that I'd be able to subscribe them to it for the time being. I tried NOT passing null into the paid plan subscription as well ([as per this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38396699/create-a-new-stripe-user-on-a-paid-plan-setting-a-trial-period-without-a-credi)), but that gave me an invalid token error.

My user model also contains the 'trial_ends_at', 'updated_at', and 'created_at' fields that the Laravel docs recommend. The Stripe customer gets added just fine, and when I try to add the paid subscriptions to the new customer in the Stripe Dashboard everything works fine.

Anyone have any ideas? Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: The issue is that Stripe's API ignores trial periods by default. You have to explicitly pass `trial_from_plan: true` instead. I don't know if Laravel Cashier supports this feature thouhg

Comment: Hmm interesting, I'll look into that more and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up figuring out I had to use the following code for my trial plans after digging through Cashier's Billable, Subscription, and SubscriptionBuilder Controllers, posting here in case anyone else runs into the same problem!

```
$user->newSubscription('My Subscription', $planToUse)->trialUntil($user->trial_ends_at)->create(null, [
                'email' => $user->email,
                'description' => $user->name
            ]);
```